# Derby Js: How to create controllers and models in single applicatoin

Tags: node.js, express, derbyjs

I am new to Derby Js. How and where to create routes to controllers. 
2- How to create Foo, Bar controllers in 'controller' folder and Foo, Bar models in 'model' folder and how to call the models in controllers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably came from Ruby or another similar MVC framework. Thing a little bit different in Derby. I advice you to:
1. Read tutorials and FAQ: https://github.com/vmakhaev/derby-docs
2. Make an app with 'derby new myapp' and play with it
3. Take a look at examples: https://github.com/codeparty/derby-examples

Comment: Ok so Derby takes a different approach, but still, it seems that a single file would get unwieldy after a while for all the routes and controller functions...is there any documentation that talks about organizing medium to large-sized projects? I wasn't able to find any (although I did see some talk about how to do this with Express, which is the middleware Derby uses)...

Comment: You should split your logic into separate files, for sure. There are a lot of ways to do it. You can take a look at this example https://github.com/switz/derby-boilerplate Bear in mind that it is for previous Derby version (0.3). But it can give you some understanding.